# What is a user friendly way of preventing users re-submitting / editing a form while it is submitting?

Tags: forms, ajax

What is the most user friendly way to block user input to form while form is submitting that can be reused i.e. so I don't have to implement it for each form?

For forms with only buttons (I have voting system similar to SE Vote up, Votes count, VoteDown):

- Should we just disable buttons/links and hope user knows what is happening?
- Should we put spinners or similar and block button    somewhere near button?
- Replace button with spinner, the show button    and remove spinner on unblock?

For normal forms:

- Should we overlay forms and put spinner in middle or some loading text (this can look ugly IMO, because forms can be different size of container)?
- Should we change mosue pointer to spinner?
- Disable all fields/buttons etc.?

Comment: what kind of input ?

Comment: @Mervin Whole form which can contain all HTML controls: textboxes, buttons, dropdowns etc. either whole form like with overlay or each control spearatly.

Comment: So I am still confused, do you plan to keep the form fields editable when a person is in the process of submitting a form?

Comment: @Mervin Like the title says, I want to block user from editing form while form is submitting until the form is submitted, after form has been submitted my usual pattern is to clear form so user can submit it agian.

Comment: If you disable form elements, what happens in instances where the user has lost connectivity while in the process of submitting the form?  If the user stops the page loading in an attempt to preserve the completed form, the user will not be able to resubmit.

Comment: One thing I have seen mis-coded in .Net websites is that the original button that has been clicked turns into a spinner image. So far so good. What the coders did not do is prevent other buttons from being clicked... so while the 'Submit' button is happily spinning away, the Cancel button could still be pressed. This was not intentional and could leave the business process in an indeterminate state!

Comment: @Nij Good point, will watch out for that. That's why I prefer overlays but, they look so ugly :(

Comment: @cimmanon There could be timeout method implemented, that can unblock form if it goes for too long or better yet ping after some time and unblock if it fails, other errors can be handled easily to unblock form.

Answer (score 29):

### **For Buttons**

I would strongly recommend looking at this [excellent example](http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/) which converts the button into an form submission indicator as well.

[image]

Here are a couple more resources you might find interesting too which show relevant progress buttons

[Ladda](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/)

[Loda Buttons](http://jquery-plugins.net/loda-button-buttons-with-loading-animation)

However if you are concerned about users trying to interact the button, **you can always disable the button as that gives the affordance that nothing more can be done with the button**.

### **For Forms**

So going by our comment conversation, what you are looking for is some kind of interaction or overlay which will inform users that the form submission is going on and hence any interaction cannot be done.

My recommendation would be to show an overlay with a message which informs the user that processing is going on and he would be getting results shortly. A good example would that be  this example of incorporating an interesting animation like how http://tweet.grader.com does while it is processing the history of a twitter handle as shown below:

[image]

This [flight tracker for ipad](http://dribbble.com/shots/334949-Flight-Tracker-for-iPad) uses a interesting simulation which shows a plane flying as shown below

[image]

[Orbitz](http://www.orbitz.com/) on form submission shows a spinning indicator to inform users content is being submitted and they have to wait as shown below

[image]

Comment: @Merivn Progress Button Styles are excellent, very creative! :)

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to do is provide visual feedback that:

1. the user clicked the button,
2. you've received that click, and
3. magic is happening to deliver the results.

Disabling the button achieved the first two goals. The items **Mervin** lists off are good ways to achieve the third goal.

The simplest response is **disable the button after it has been clicked once.** You can add in other loading / progress bars and animations (like the ones **Mervin** listed), but those aren't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's fairly common to provide a transaction number as part of the form sent down to the user, so that if they rePOST the same form you can detect this and reject it.

(This is particularly important if the POST is coming from Java. There is a known bug in Java where someone forgot that while GETs are idempotent -- ie, it's promised to be safe to issue the same GET several times in a row -- POSTs are not. As a result, if the server is responding slowly Java's POST code may resubmit the transaction even if the user has not said to do so. Sun/Oracle have declined to fix this for fear that someone, somewhere, may be relying upon the broken behavior. There is a system property that can be set to disable that bug, and I highly recommend doing so, but it's another good reason to design the system to recognize unintended rePOSTs.)